# How do I change the language of only the login page?

Tags: login, multi-language, language, wp-login-form

My wordpress blog is set up as `de_DE`.
This means that my login page is also displayed in `de_DE`.

I would like to **only** have the login page in `en_US`.

So, **How would I programmatically change a single page's language?**

**Note**: I have WPML but I don't wish to use it, I only want to change one page on the whole site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will need to go in a plug-in, just put the following inside a file (`login-languge.php`) in `wp-content/plugins/`

```
/*
Plugin Name:  Log-in Language
Plugin URI:   http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-only-the-login-page
Description:  Changes the language for log-in/register screens only
Author:       Stephen Harris
Author URI:   http://stephenharris.info
Version:      1.0
License:      GNU GPL 2
*/
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'wpse72696_login_language_init');

function wpse72696_login_language_init(){
    if( in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) ) ){
        add_filter('locale', 'wpse72692_login_language',10);
    }
}

function wpse72692_login_language( $locale ){
    return 'en_US';
}
```

Comment: Can this be added to my functions.php?

Comment: No - it can only work as a plug-in. But that's not more difficult than using it in `functions.php`

Comment: @StephenHaris So I would just dump this into a my_plugin.php and place it in my plugins dir?
Or do I have to create a whole plugin class and so forth?

Comment: Yup, but with comment headers. Plugin class isn't necessary. See edit :)

Answer (score 4):

You can repalce `define( 'WPLANG',  'de_DE');` in your wp-config.php  by this code structuer.

```
if (basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)) == 'wp-login.php'){
    define( 'WPLANG',  'en_US');
} else {
    define( 'WPLANG',  'de_DE');
}
```

Comment: won't this effect performance?

Comment: nope =) (less that adding filter...)

Comment: I went for the plugin answer since this is slightly more hassle. For anybody else viewing, this answer also works. Thank You @CodeMonkey!

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this in your `functions.php` using [`unload_textdomain($domain)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unload_textdomain)

```
add_action('init', 'remove_login_translation');
function remove_login_translation() {
    if( in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) ) ) {
        unload_textdomain('default');
    }
}
```

Comment: so this would simply revert to english and then switch back when I enter the admin area?

Comment: sure, this will unload the default translation only on the login pages, and translation will load normally on other pages, whether admin or front-end.