# How do I change a plugin language of only one page?

Tags: plugins, multi-language, language

My WordPress blog is set up as `nl_NL`. This means that my [bookly plugin](http://booking-wp-plugin.com/) is also displayed in `nl_NL`.

In the Plugin directory there is a folder languages with loads of other languages.

I have one page in three different languages `nl_NL`, `de_DE`, `en_EN`, on this page I would like the booking plugin to be displayed in the correct language.

I changed the page language via page id from `nl_NL` to `de_DE`

Via the `function.php`, but this had no effect.

```
function get_top_parent_page_id() { 
    global $post; 

    if ($post->ancestors) { 
        return end($post->ancestors); 
    } else { 
        return $post->ID; 
    } 
}

function addLangMetaTag (){
    $postLanguage = "nl_NL";
    if (is_page()) {
    $svPageID = get_top_parent_page_id(); // ID of parent page
            if ($svPageID == "13040") { // ID of the "på svenska" page
                $postLanguage = "de_DE";    
            }
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"content-language\" content=\"" . $postLanguage . "\">";
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_head', 'addLangMetaTag' );

function language_tagger_change_html_lang_tag() {
    return "dir=\"ltr\" lang=\"" . 
language_tagger_determin_lang_tag() . "\"";
}

function language_tagger_determin_lang_tag() {
    $postLanguage = 'nl_NL'; // default language
    if (is_page()) {
    $svPageID = get_top_parent_page_id(); // ID of parent page
    if ($svPageID == "13040") { // ID of the "på svenska" page
                $postLanguage = "de_DE";    
            }
    }
    return $postLanguage;
}

add_filter('language_attributes', 
'language_tagger_change_html_lang_tag');
```

I think it will only look at the WordPress `config.php` `define('WPLANG', 'nl_NL');`
I have also been reading [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-only-the-login-page#) maybe I could combine something?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this is to use the "Ceceppa Multilingua" plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ceceppa-multilingua/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is changing the http-equiv meta tag. Changing the HTML tags doesn't change the language of the page content. It just tells browsers (and bots/spiders) what language the content is **supposed** to be.

If you want to change the language the content is displayed in, you need to change the textdomain for your bookly plugin.

You can do that with [WP's `plugin_locale` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_plugin_textdomain/).  That filter runs when the language files are being loaded and it allows you to change the textdomain (de_DE or nl_NL) that is used.

```
add_filter( 'plugin_locale', function( $locale ) {
    if (is_page()) {
        $svPageID = get_top_parent_page_id(); // ID of parent page
        if ($svPageID == "13040") { // ID of the "på svenska" page
            $locale = "de_DE";    
        }
    }
    return $locale;
});
```

If you need to change more than just the plugin's output (i.e. the language of the entire page), then you probably [`determine_locale` filter in the `determine_locale()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/determine_locale/).  It would be the same as above, but with `determine_locale` as the filter hook.