# How do I change the language of the login page to Arabic?

Tags: login, multi-language, wp-login-form, language

I have a website where the backend is english and the frontend is Arabic. My wordpress login is in English but i want to make it Arabic.

I have tried the first solution listed here [How do I change the language of only the login page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-only-the-login-page) but it is not working for me.

In the code by @Stephen Harris, i changed return 'en_US'; to return 'ar' but nothing happened to my login page.

Comment: Have you tried goting to the settings in the dashboard panel and changing the language there?

Comment: Have you definitely got the Arabic .mo file downloaded, i.e. does Arabic appear in the list of possible site languages on the settings, general page?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast if i were to follow the approach you are suggesting i think i will be changing the whole site language and not just the login page language

Comment: @Rup yes Arabic is part of my site language